# Trouble installing truffle

Tags: truffle

I have been trying to install truffle framework with this command [npm install truffle -g], but I am getting this error. can someone please help me?[image: error while installing truffle]

Comment: There is no error message, it should be installed. If you try to run truffle does it show an error?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g truffle` should work, if the case is related to permission use
`sudo`